# Inconsistent data and bad answers using strtotime and date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Using PHP 5.3 and given the string `Sat, 20 Oct 2012 05:00:00 GMT`:

```
print $start;
$start = strtotime($start);
var_dump($start);
$hour = date('H:i A', $start);
die($hour);
```

That snippet of code in my program returns this:

```
Sat, 20 Oct 2012 05:00:00 GMT
int(1350709200)
00:00 AM
```

The `var_dump` is correct, but the date returns a bad answer.

Note, also, that changing that snippet to read:

```
print $start;
$start = strtotime($start);
die($start);
$hour = date('H:i A', $start);
die($hour);
```

returns:

```
Sat, 20 Oct 2012 05:00:00 GMT
```

The first die returns an empty string, a null, which I can only assume is actually a boolean FALSE.

So I'm actually having two different problems, here.  The same answer returns two different things depending on if I `var_dump` or die, and the second is that date appears to be receiving the FALSE answer, not the `var_dump` answer.

Help?

Comment: I'd say that using `die()` to debug a variable is not the way to go. Instead if you want to debug variables and then kill the program, use `var_dump($foo); die();`.

Comment: Also, I guess you do realize that `die()` ends your script; which makes the script only run til line 3 on your second example. Anything behind that will never be executed.

Comment: Could be timezone related. What timezone is your system set to, and what timezone is your php.ini set to?

Comment: Which timezone do you have set for `date.default_timezone`?

Comment: try adding date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); before the code, that should tell you if its a timezone issue

Comment: I set it to America/Chicago' at the begining of the script (date_default_timezone_set ( 'America/Chicago' );)

Comment: And that is utc -5 at the moment. so 05:00 GMT = 00:00 in America/Chicago DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you have said, you are setting the timezone to America/Chicago. When you call strtotime you are explicitly specifying GMT in the string. When you then put the timestamp into Date, it is taking the timestamp and giving you the time in America/Chicago, 5 hours before GMT, which is why it is 00:00AM.

You are using 5.3. I would suggest using the [DateTime](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object instead of strtotime() and date(). Its a bit easier to work with timezones etc, and the var_dumps are useful. Create a DateTime from user input or db value and then pass that around in your code instead of timestamps.

Comment: I was trying to use 24 hour time with AM/PM.  Stupid mistake.